# What kind of sort is this?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm new to sorting and unsure which sort is the code below. Thanks in advance.

```
for (int x = 1; x < arr.length; x++) {
    for (int y = x; y > 0 && arr[y - 1] > arr[y]; y--) {
        int t = arr[y];
        arr[y] = arr[y - 1];
        arr[y - 1] = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a bubble sort I believe.

Answer (score 4):

It's an insertion sort.  See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) which includes a version of your algorithm (in pseudocode near the top).